# Python: use string variable as search pattern in regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to search a nucleotide sequence (composed of only A,C,G,T) for a user-defined pattern, using regex:

The relevant code is as follows:

```
    match = re.match(r'{0}'.format(pattern), sequence)
```

match always returns None, where I need it to return the part of the sequence that matches the user query...

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is how I constructed the search pattern:

```
   askMotif = raw_input('Enter a motif to search for it in the sequence (The wildcard character ‘?’ represents any nucleotide in that position, and * represents none or many nucleotides in that position.): ')
listMotif= []    
letterlist = ['A','C','G','T', 'a', 'c','g','t']
for letter in askMotif:
    if letter in letterlist:
        a = letter.capitalize()
        listMotif.append(a)
    if letter == '?':
        listMotif.append('.')
    if letter == '*':
        listMotif.append('*?')
pattern = ''
for searcher in listMotif:
    pattern+=searcher
```

Not very pythonic, I know...

Comment: can your post your test case?

Comment: do you mean the sequence that i'm searching? it's really long... like more than 1000 chars

Comment: What happens when you hard code the patterns?

Comment: Just a small portion of it should be good enough.

Comment: 'GATCCTCCATATACAACGGTATCTCCACCTCAGGTTTAGATCTCAACAACGGAACCATTGCCGACATGAGACAGTTAGGTATCGTCGAGAGTTACAAGC'

Comment: I think you mean `'*' -> '.*?'` for 0 or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine:

```
>>> tgt='AGAGAGAGACGTACACAC'
>>> re.match(r'{}'.format('ACGT'), tgt)
>>> re.search(r'{}'.format('ACGT'), tgt)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10a5d6920>
```

I think it may because you mean to use search vs match

---

Hint on your posted code:

```
prompt='''\
    Enter a motif to search for it in the sequence 
    (The wildcard character '?' represents any nucleotide in that position, 
     and * represents none or many nucleotides in that position.)
'''
pattern=None
while pattern==None:
    print prompt
    user_input=raw_input('>>> ')
    letterlist = ['A','C','G','T', '?', '*']
    user_input=user_input.upper()
    if len(user_input)>1 and all(c in letterlist for c in user_input):
        pattern=user_input.replace('?', '.').replace('*', '.*?')
    else:
        print 'Bad pattern, please try again'
```

Comment: thanks, that works. will accept your answer when stackoverflow allows me to do so :) (in six minutes for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

`re.match()` only matches at the beginning of the sequence. Perhaps you need `re.search()`?

```
>>> re.match(r'{0}'.format('bar'), 'foobar').group(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> re.search(r'{0}'.format('bar'), 'foobar').group(0)
'bar'
```